# How to keep 4G on while on WI-FI

Tags: samsung

My home Wi-Fi connection doesn't have Internet access, so I need to keep my 4g on while connected to the WI-FI. I tried "smart network switch" and it doesn't work, it is kicking the WI-FI off because it doesn't have Internet access. Also tried the "Download Booster" same thing. It kicks the WI-FI off.

Any way to have them both connected? My Wi-Fi as LAN and my 4g for Internet navigation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of until Marshmallow, stock Android does not support connecting to both WLAN and Data network simultaneously.

You may keep them both turned on, but the OS will then choose to connect to WLAN or Data depending on Internet access and network quality.

Reference: Personal experience only.